# Transformations that map points inside the sphere to points inside the sphere

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-geometry

I am trying to figure out what is the most general linear transformation that maps points inside the unit sphere to points inside the unit sphere. I am slightly abusing the word linear here by allowing also translations.

Thus I am looking for $4 \times 4$ matrices that when applied on the vector $v=(1,x,y,z)^T$ with $x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 1$ gives me another vector $v'=(1,x',y',z')$ that satisfies $x'^2+y'^2+z'^2 \leq 1$.
I know this matrix must have as its first row $(1,0,0,0)$ but I am curious to know if this matrices have some name and if their properties are known. By the  properties they have they should form a monoid or a semi group with an identity operation. Any help or useful reference on the structure of these objects will be much appreciated...

Comment: The term you want is "affine transformation."

Comment: I like your trick for packaging an affine transformation as a matrix

Comment: It so happens that every affine transformation of the sphere is an ellipsoid. You'll probably want to figure out how the parameters of that ellipsoid are determined by the transformation. The most challenging part of this problem, I suspect, will be figuring out the translation aspect. On what surface can you place the ellipsoid so that it just kisses the inside of the sphere? I don't personally have a clue.

Comment: Thanks @dfeuer . I was trying to understand what you meant by an ellipsoid. Your answer in some limit reduces to the simplest case of affine transformation, which are rotations that can always be represented as a line in space (well, a direction plus a rotation magnitude) which are a extreme case of an ellipsoid. Do you know of any reference where I can read more about what you explain?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The calculations involved are going to be a bit hairy, but the basic idea is that by stretching, shearing, and rotating the sphere, you produce an ellipsoid. You can (with some hairy calculations) determine things like the orientations and lengths of the axes of the ellipsoid, which will allow you to figure out what rotation would align the axes to your coordinate system, at which point the problem reduces to figuring out how you can translate an ellipsoid while keeping it inside the sphere.